# How do I convert a DateTime object to YYMMDD format?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, formatting, format

Um, probably a really simple question, but I just noticed that I have no idea on how to convert `DateTime.Now` to the format YYMMDD, so for example today (5. November 2009) would be "091105".

I know there are overloads to `DateTime.Now.ToString()` where you can pass in a format string, but I have not found the right format e.g. for short year format (09 instead of 2009).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd")
```

You may also find the following two posts on MSDN useful as they contain a lot of info about DateTime formatting:

[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)
[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. :)

Comment: @Rob: nice cheat sheet! Very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative that you can do this is by:

```
var formattedDate = string.Format("{0:yyMMdd}", DateTime.Now);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The reference for the format string is at [MSDN: Custom DateTime Format Specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28VS.80%29.aspx).

What you are looking for specifically is:

**yy** Represents the year as a two-digit number. If the year has more than two digits, only the two low-order digits appear in the result. If the year has fewer than two digits, the number is padded with leading zeroes to achieve two digits.

**MM** Represents the month as a number from 01 through 12. A single-digit month is formatted with a leading zero.

**dd** Represents the day of the month as a number from 01 through 31. A single-digit day is formatted with a leading zero.